# How to ping from Zabbix agent?

Tags: ping, agent, zabbix

Is it possible to ping from Zabbix agent and pass that data into Zabbix server? I would like to be able to get response time from the agent.

I read that it is possible by using fping, would be great if someone could guide me to the correct path.

Thank you,
Rijath Mohammed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While that is not currently available out of the box, you can implement such a functionality using a feature called "user parameters". This [forum thread](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=20592) has a simple example:

```
UserParameter=myping[*],/etc/zabbix/fping -q $1;echo $?
```

Although for you the path to fping is likely to be `/usr/sbin/fping` or `/usr/bin/fping`.

You can read more about user parameters in the official manual: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters .

While I haven't ever configured that, it would be similar on Windows - see [this forum thread](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=42338) for some inspiration.

And if you would like to see this feature implemented out of the box, make sure to vote on this [feature request](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-739).

Comment: Hi Richlv, do you know how to get it work on Windows agents?

Comment: linked to some windows example in the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, Richlv. :)

Comment: how do you make a trigger if no response (then not numeric response) (im using the windows version but the problem still the same) ?

Comment: This isn't a forum - please check the Zabbix documentation, and if a specific solution does not work for you, add a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working using the below powershell script, :)

```
$Test = test-connection google.com -count 1
$Test.responsetime
```

This will just return the response time for Google.com and that value is passed to Zabbix using the below user parameter:

```
UnsafeUserParameters=1
UserParameter=ping.google,C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\zabbix\pinggoogle.ps1
```

I am calling this parameter from Zabbix using the key "**ping.google**"

Comment: You don't need to enable UnsafeUserParameters for this. Enabling that parameter is equal to enabling remote commands.

Comment: how do you create the item/trigger? because error doesnt trigger the alarm in my case.